# removing a particular pattern from a given string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-re

i would like generate the following output from the string `"[cid:12d32323232dde]foo foo foo \r\n\r\n\r\n[cid:123fsr3ef234fsdfere]\r\n"`

expected output

`foo foo foo \r\n\r\n\r\n`

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - remove all `[cid:...]` blocks and any newlines/carriage-returns trailing them?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "[cid:12d32323232dde]foo foo foo \r\n\r\n\r\n[cid:123fsr3ef234fsdfere]\r\n"
>>> re.sub(r"\[cid:(.+?)\][\r\n]*", "", s)
'foo foo foo \r\n\r\n\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex search

```
import regex as re

x = r"[cid:12d32323232dde]foo foo foo \r\n\r\n\r\n[cid:123fsr3ef234fsdfere]\r\n"

re.search("\]([^]]+)\[", x)[1]
```

1. First we will import the regex
2. We will make the string - raw string

   ```
   x = r"" -> the r before the string

   -> we will get the next result with raw string
   foo foo foo \r\n\r\n\r\n

   -> we will get the next result without raw string
   foo foo foo 
   ...
   ```
3. We do a regex search to get text between ] and [, the re.search method return a match object, the match object contains 2 items.

   ```
   re.search("\]([^]]+)\[", x)[0]
   -> first one with ] and [

   re.search("\]([^]]+)\[", x)[1]
   -> second one without ] and [
   ```